# how to filter a variable in a column and plot the other ones

Tags: python, plot

I have a `column df['order_status]`, there are 5 values in this columns:

```
df['order_status'].value_counts()
```

I would like to filter '`delivered`' and plot the other 4 values(`shipped, canceled, invoiced, processing`). What should I do to filter the '`delivered`'?

Thank you!

```
df['order_status'].value_counts()

delivered     3467
shipped         48
canceled        25
invoiced        24
processing      20
```

Comment: What you mean by "filter"

Comment: Hi my desire output is 
data = df['order_status'].value_counts() could be 4 values:
 shipped         48
canceled        25
invoiced        24
processing      20

and then, I can plot this data